# Javascript calls form submit -> calls -> Javascript (ajax call) not getting returns from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a `<span>` in `<a>`

```
 <a class="small-yellow-button float-right" id="signin" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span>Sign In</span>
 </a>
```

called by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signin").click(function() {
    $('#form-signin').submit(); 
    });
});
```

which calls:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form-signin" onSubmit="login(); return false;" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="on">

function login()
{
   $.post(....), function(data)
{
  // code does NOT reach here.
  alert(data);
}
}
```

this function issues an ajax call, i get the request on the server and send the correct response back, but somehow i am not getting the response in this function. I know this function `login()` works because I can call it directly, but somehow I have to go through the loop of javascript->form submit->javascript for my project.

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

I'd just remove the whole `onsubmit` from the form and use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signin").click(login);
});
```

To prevent the form from submitting normally, add this inside the document ready block:

```
$('#form-signin').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Now, you say the `login` function works, but the code you posted for it certainly doesn't...

Comment: I have to keep the design of javascript-> form.submit() -> javascript.

Comment: yes, i didn't post complete code, but the entire login() is correct.

Comment: But the `form.submit()` just calls `login` and prevents the default behavior!

Comment: @bfavaretto It has no default behavior, `action` is empty

Comment: @PitaJ Then the default behavior is to submit to the current page, isn't it?

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm not sure about that

Comment: @user1418326 Are you positive `login` works? And, when you call it via click->submit->login, do you see the request being fired on the console? Do you get any errors on the console?

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
$.post( url , data , function(data) { 
   //code
 });
```

Comment: yes, i didn't post complete code, but the entire login() is correct.

Comment: @user1418326 Do you get any errors?  Like "ReferenceError: data is not defined" or "Unexpected token ("

Comment: No error. I debugged through the server side code, it sends out the response, but the javascript function just couldn't receive the response.